# Add number week in timesheet Odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-16

I'm trying to add number of week in the grid of timesheet in Odoo V16.

Like this :
[image]

But my new function in my inherit js doesn't be call and i don't know why ?

This is my xml file (inherit from web_grid) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
    <t t-inherit="web_grid.Table" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
        <xpath expr="//th[@class='o_grid_title_header']" position="inside">
                <b>"<t t-esc="numberWeek"/>"</b>
        </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>
```

And this is my inherit js (inherit from web_grid.grid_renderer.js) :

```
odoo.define('my_custom_addon.GridRenderer', function (require) {
    "use strict";
        var GridRenderer = require('web_grid.GridRenderer');

        class ModifiedGridRenderer extends GridRenderer {
            get numberWeek() {
                console.log(this.props.timeBoundariesContext);
                return "Week 26";
            };
        };

        return ModifiedGridRenderer;
});
```

My xml file is correctly inherit because when i had manually number week, it appear without problems.
But when i use my function numberWeek in my xml, i don't have any error but nothing appear.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank's in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing it's that your Custom Renderer `ModifiedGridRenderer` wouldn't be used at all by the Grid View

https://github.com/odoo/enterprise/blob/59cfadfabc246d782e4a359d365efb11b8af7ae7/web_grid/static/src/js/grid_view.js#L24

You could patch the original `GridRenderer` OWL Component to add your function

or

You could directly set the `GridView.config.Renderer = ModifiedGridRenderer` in order to be used by the GridView

Answer (score 0):

Thank to aekis.dev !

Indeed the patch work great.

This is my code example :

```
/** @odoo-module **/
import { patch } from 'web.utils';

var GridRenderer = require('web_grid.GridRenderer');


patch(GridRenderer.prototype, 'Number Week', {
    get numberWeek() {
        //timeBoundariesContext -> get the start and end date of the selected date in timesheet
        console.log(this.props.timeBoundariesContext);
        return "Week 26";
    }
});
```